# Is there some equivalent in Java to Ruby's Nokogiri::XML::EntityDecl?

Tags: java, nokogiri, dtd, jdom, mathml

I have an issue where I need to prepend a DTD containing ENTITYs bracketed in the definition to an existing XML document.

For example, working from the specification for MathML in DAISY at http://www.daisy.org/projects/mathml/mathml-in-daisy-spec.html, say I am given this XML by an outside source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dtbook PUBLIC "-//NISO//DTD dtbook 2005-2//EN"
 "http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/dtbook-2005-2.dtd">
<dtbook xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/dtbook/" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    version="2005-3" xml:lang="eng">
    <m:math xmlns:dtbook="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/dtbook/"
  id="math0001" dtbook:smilref="nativemathml.smil#math0001"
  altimg="nativemathml0001.png"
  alttext="sigma-summation UnderScript i equals zero OverScript infinity EndScripts x Subscript i">
      <m:mrow>
        <m:mstyle displaystyle='true'>
          <m:munderover>
            <m:mo>&#x2211;</m:mo>
            <m:mrow>
              <m:mi>i</m:mi><m:mo>=</m:mo><m:mn>0</m:mn>
            </m:mrow>
            <m:mi>&#x221E;</m:mi>
          </m:munderover>
          <m:mrow>
            <m:msub>
              <m:mi>x</m:mi>
              <m:mi>i</m:mi>
            </m:msub>
          </m:mrow>
        </m:mstyle>
      </m:mrow>
</m:math>
</dtbook>
```

I want to add the ENTITY definitions from the specification to make this book support MathML, so that the result looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dtbook PUBLIC "-//NISO//DTD dtbook 2005-2//EN"
 "http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/dtbook-2005-2.dtd"
 [
  <!ENTITY % MATHML.prefixed "INCLUDE" >
  <!ENTITY % MATHML.prefix "m">
  <!ENTITY % MATHML.Common.attrib
          "xlink:href    CDATA       #IMPLIED
          xlink:type     CDATA       #IMPLIED
          class          CDATA       #IMPLIED
          style          CDATA       #IMPLIED
          id             ID          #IMPLIED
          xref           IDREF       #IMPLIED
          other          CDATA       #IMPLIED
          xmlns:dtbook   CDATA       #FIXED 'http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/dtbook/'
          dtbook:smilref CDATA       #IMPLIED"
  >
  <!ENTITY % mathML2 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD MathML 2.0//EN"
             "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd"
  >
  %mathML2;
  <!ENTITY % externalFlow "| m:math">
  <!ENTITY % externalNamespaces "xmlns:m CDATA #FIXED
    'http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML'">
 ]
>
<dtbook xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/dtbook/" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
    version="2005-3" xml:lang="eng">
    <m:math xmlns:dtbook="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/dtbook/"
  id="math0001" dtbook:smilref="nativemathml.smil#math0001"
  altimg="nativemathml0001.png"
  alttext="sigma-summation UnderScript i equals zero OverScript infinity EndScripts x Subscript i">
      <m:mrow>
        <m:mstyle displaystyle='true'>
          <m:munderover>
            <m:mo>&#x2211;</m:mo>
            <m:mrow>
              <m:mi>i</m:mi><m:mo>=</m:mo><m:mn>0</m:mn>
            </m:mrow>
            <m:mi>&#x221E;</m:mi>
          </m:munderover>
          <m:mrow>
            <m:msub>
              <m:mi>x</m:mi>
              <m:mi>i</m:mi>
            </m:msub>
          </m:mrow>
        </m:mstyle>
      </m:mrow>
</m:math>
</dtbook>
```

In Ruby, there is a method in Nokogiri that can be used to add these ENTITY definitions that looks like this:
    Nokogiri::XML::EntityDecl.new("MATHML.prefixed", doc, MATHML_ENTITY_DECL_TYPE, nil, nil, "INCLUDE")

Is there an equivalent to this in Java?  We are using JDOM to manipulate our XML documents, but the JDOM DocType class doesn't appear to support these entity definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JDOM you should be able to parse the original document, and pull the DTDContent node from the document.

Your code would look something like:

```
Document doc = saxBuilder.build(myxmlfile);
DocType dtd = doc.getDocType();
```

That `dtd` content should be the reference to the `dtbook` reference.

You can now take the string-representation of the mathml declarations, and include them as an internalsubset of the DocType (perhaps you want to read it from a file, or as a System resource, or something).

```
String internal = "  <!ENTITY % MATHML.prefixed \"INCLUDE\" >\n"
    + "  <!ENTITY % MATHML.prefix \"m\">\n"
    + ......

dtd.setInternalSubset(internal);
```

See: http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/DocType.html#setInternalSubset(java.lang.String)

This will modify the declaration, and, if you output the XML, you should have the content you expect:

```
XMLOutputter xout = new XMLOutputter();
xout.output(doc, System.out);
```

Comment: This is interesting.  I had loaded a sample file with the combined DAISY/MathML DTD and in the debugger I could see that the internalSubset of the DocType was empty.  When I printed the document back out with XMLOutputter, similar to what you have here, the internal ENTITY definitions were stripped out.  We are using JDOM 1 so I wonder if it is an issue with that version or I am missing something in my usage.  I will try setting the internalSubset as the next experiment.

Comment: You should be using JDOM 2.x ;-) It's alteady half-a-decade-old

Comment: Believe me, when our budget and time permits, we will.  But It's not really up to me.  This code base is ~10 years old and there are lots of little references to JDOM 1.1.3 everywhere.

Comment: I did try both JDOM 1.1.3 and JDOM 2 and both are refusing to read the InternalSubset entities in from a file using SaxBuilder.build(InputStream).   On the other hand, adding internal subset entities to to a file without them, following your instructions here, works fine.  Now I'll have research how not to lose those entities when we reread in that file for further processing.  Thanks!